# Use OLAP Cube in PivotTableWizard

Tags: c#, pivot-table, olap, cube

I need to create a workshee in excel which has a pivot table using an OLAP Cube as its data source. And I don't know what parameters set in the Workbook.PivotTableWizard to create the table and indicating the Cube as DataSource.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you not just record a macro and look at the recorded VBA code?

Comment: Hi, I just generated the ODC file and done, opened that file with Excel and the pivot table was there.